# 500 server error with two functions with the same name

Tags: php, function

I'm using PHP 5.4 and when I do this:

```
<?php
function test(){}
function test(){}
?>
```

I get a 500 server error in my browser instead of a PHP error. Is this a bug? Do you guys experience the same?

Comment: I get a status code 200 with the message: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare test() (previously declared in *.php:3) in *.php on line 3`

Comment: I get a 500 with my nginx/php-fpm setup and a 200 with my Apache/mod_php setup. I think perhaps xdebug might be tweaking the latter.

Comment: What are your error settings like? Enable `display_errors` and the like.

Comment: @dirt: It doesn't change anything if I enable display_errors.

Comment: @Alex Howansky: Do you think I've to report it somewhere?

Comment: I don't think it's an error. A PHP fatal *should* be a 500.

Comment: I think it's strange so I thought is was maybe a bug. Took me a lot of time to figure out that I had declared to functions with the same name which cause this error. It was easier for me to just see `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare test()` instead of a not anything saying 500 error.

Comment: If you're using IE you actually have to go into your internet options and under Advanced **disable** the option `Show friendly errors` as I've seen this hide detailed error messages and instead show a default.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, so that option isn't there. And I've tested it to in IE and FF.

Answer (score 3):

The output of your server when an error occurs depends on your server setting. Because of security it's a good idea to not expose the real error message on a production server. Instead it's logged somewhere, usually you can find it somewhere around /var/log/apache2/error_log

Comment: Thanks! But I'm at a shared hosting environment so I don't have access to that file.

Comment: The location may vary, do you have some kind of log directory somewhere? If not ask your provider, he should provide you the error logs.

Comment: Found it in the Direct Admin control panel! Thanks!